# Unable to get the required gwtopenlayers jars

Tags: gwt-openlayers

How can I get the jars for org.gwtopenmaps.demo.openlayers.client.basic and org.gwtopenmaps.demo.openlayers.client.components.store packages.I want to import AbstractExample and ShowcaseExampleStore classes into my java file.﻿

Answer (score 0):

You won't find any jars for that, as the showcase is only available as a war.

Just download the GWT-OpenLayers sourcecode at github extract what you want.